# Get value from xml and calculate

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, ruby-on-rails-6

I am getting the amounts from an xml file but I need to sum them to check.
I am using Ruby on rails with the Nokogiri gem
**Example from xml file:**

```
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="15101514" NoIdentificacion="PL/762/EXP/ES/2015-16665610" Cantidad="52.967" ClaveUnidad="LTR" Descripcion="MAGNA (LT)" ValorUnitario="16.34" Importe="865.74">
          <cfdi:Impuestos>
            <cfdi:Traslados>
              <cfdi:Traslado Base="842.59" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="134.81"/>
            </cfdi:Traslados>
          </cfdi:Impuestos>
        </cfdi:Concepto>
<cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="15101514" NoIdentificacion="PL/767/EXP/ES/2015-8515840" Cantidad="35.045" ClaveUnidad="LTR" Descripcion="MAGNA (LT)" ValorUnitario="16.34" Importe="572.80">
      <cfdi:Impuestos>
        <cfdi:Traslados>
          <cfdi:Traslado Base="557.49" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="89.20"/>
        </cfdi:Traslados>
      </cfdi:Impuestos>
    </cfdi:Concepto>
    <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="15101514" NoIdentificacion="PL/762/EXP/ES/2015-16665910" Cantidad="21.992" ClaveUnidad="LTR" Descripcion="MAGNA (LT)" ValorUnitario="16.34" Importe="359.45">
      <cfdi:Impuestos>
        <cfdi:Traslados>
          <cfdi:Traslado Base="349.84" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="55.97"/>
        </cfdi:Traslados>
      </cfdi:Impuestos>
    </cfdi:Concepto>
    <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="15101514" NoIdentificacion="PL/762/EXP/ES/2015-16665560" Cantidad="25.002" ClaveUnidad="LTR" Descripcion="MAGNA (LT)" ValorUnitario="16.34" Importe="408.62">
      <cfdi:Impuestos>
        <cfdi:Traslados>
          <cfdi:Traslado Base="397.69" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="63.63"/>
        </cfdi:Traslados>
      </cfdi:Impuestos>
    </cfdi:Concepto>
```

I managed to obtain all the amounts and taxes with these line of code:

```
                array = []
                array_i = []
                file = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(params[:consumption][:factura]))    
                doc_pass = file.xpath("//cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Conceptos/cfdi:Concepto")    
                doc_pass.each do |pass|
                    hash_importe = {}
                    hash_importe[:total] = pass['Importe']
                    array << hash_importe
                end       
                doc_pass2 = file.xpath("//cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Conceptos/cfdi:Concepto/cfdi:Impuestos/cfdi:Traslados/cfdi:Traslado")    
                doc_pass2.each do |pass2|
                    hash_impuesto = {}
                    hash_impuesto[:tax] = pass2['Importe']
                    array_i << hash_impuesto
                end
```

these are the results I get from the xml file:

```
(byebug) array
[{:importe=>"865.74"}, {:importe=>"572.80"}, {:importe=>"359.45"}, {:importe=>"408.62"}, {:importe=>"324.48"}, {:importe=>"649.64"}, {:importe=>"823.45"}, {:importe=>"545.15"}, {:importe=>"428.02"}, {:importe=>"527.21"}, {:importe=>"487.67"}, {:importe=>"331.72"}, {:importe=>"511.64"}, {:importe=>"406.67"}, {:importe=>"820.81"}, {:importe=>"1635.54"}, {:importe=>"484.14"}, {:importe=>"564.83"}, {:importe=>"1463.30"}]
(byebug) array_i
[{:importe=>"134.81"}, {:importe=>"89.20"}, {:importe=>"55.97"}, {:importe=>"63.63"}, {:importe=>"50.52"}, {:importe=>"101.18"}, {:importe=>"128.21"}, {:importe=>"84.88"}, {:importe=>"66.73"}, {:importe=>"82.10"}, {:importe=>"75.90"}, {:importe=>"51.58"}, {:importe=>"79.67"}, {:importe=>"63.33"}, {:importe=>"127.80"}, {:importe=>"254.69"}, {:importe=>"75.36"}, {:importe=>"87.92"}, {:importe=>"227.84"}]
```

- 

now what I want is to sum both values(importe + impuesto) ​​for example:

- 865.74 + 134.81
- 572.80 + 89.20
- 359.45 + 55.97

- 

I am new with rails, I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an array with results if both arrays have the same size(I think yes), like this:

```
(0..array.size - 1).each_with_object([]) { |i, obj| obj <<  array[i][:importe].to_f + array_i[i][:importe].to_f }
```

result:

```
[1000.55, 662.0, 415.41999999999996, 472.25, 375.0, 750.8199999999999, 951.6600000000001, 630.03, 494.75, 609.3100000000001, 563.57, 383.3, 591.31, 470.0, 948.6099999999999, 1890.23, 559.5, 652.75, 1691.1399999999999]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` method to combine values at corresponding index of two arrays

```
result = array.zip(array_i)
  .map { |importe, impuesto| importe[:importe].to_f + impuesto[:importe].to_f }
```

Or can be simplified more for your concrete data structure

```
result = array.zip(array_i).map { |hashes| hashes.sum {|h| h[:importe].to_f }}
```

Better approach would be if you extract `Concepto` object with `Impuesto` and `Importe` values directly from xml, then you don't need to combine different arrays, but use nicely structured object.